# Make hibernate point to the same DB connection as DBUnit

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hsqldb, dbunit

I am using hiberante jpa to connect to a mysql database.

My persistence-unit in my persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="inventoryManager">          

        <!--some settings-->

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory?useSSL=false&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneS‌​hift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1234"/>

            <!--Hibernate properties-->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

My DAO´s are using this connection to execute all the operations with the database.

I am also using DBUnit for the tests, but I am using an in-memory database(hsql). and its configuration in my test case constructor looks like this:

```
       System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_DRIVER_CLASS, "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" );
       System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_CONNECTION_URL, "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:db" );
       System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_USERNAME, "sa" );
       System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_PASSWORD, "" );
       System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_SCHEMA, "db" );
```

So when I run a test that calls one DAO. The DAO instantiates an entityManager which points to the mysql connetion specified in the persistence.xml

The question is: How do I make the entityManager inside my DAO to point to my in-memory database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you are not using Spring? What about Maven?

Comment: I am not using spring.. Maven I am

Comment: Try creating a 2nd persistence.xml under src/test/resources/META-INF with the relevant values. Resources under src/test should take priority when tests are running.

Comment: It works! so easy when you know what to do.. thank you so much Alan..

Comment: There is something else.. For my database control.. I am using liquibase.. But in the case of the tests I just auto-generated the schema by the hibernate annotations.. It works, but doesnt seem correct.. Do you know if there is a way to run my liquibase changelog inside this in-memory db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are not using Spring you can try a Maven based solution. This involves creating a separate persistence.xml under src/test/resources/META-INF with the relevant properties.

When running your tests this persistence.xml should take precedence over the one in src/main/resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

1.Create a datasource bean pointing to In Memory DB something like below

`<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl"
                value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:/data/data.db" />
</bean>`

2.Define a EntityManagerFactory which will refer to this DataSource.

3.Add both these beans in a testConfig.xml

4.Run with JUnit

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations ={ "testconfig.xml" })
```

Comment: Where does he mention that he is using Spring?

Comment: Yes by mistake I overlooked it, he is not using Spring.